# winform appliacation (service) upload and download files from OneDrive(SkyDrive)

Tags: c#, onedrive

I have winform application, that send files and download files to/from OneDrive. I have login, password and app key. I have to use oaAutentification but I generate service without user interface.
Help me thanks.

Thanks, I tried .Net client, OneDrive and oauth20_desktop.srf but user must click to New windows with allow permision

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure exactly what you're really asking here. Have you tried using the special `oauth20_desktop.srf` endpoint in the redirect URL?

> https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf

This is specifically for applications such as desktop programs and mobile apps.

Note: you'll still have to host the authentication session using a web browser control. Once the user logs in, you can then pick off the access token from the end of the URL when Microsoft redirects them to the `desktop.srf` page. You'll have to hook into the `Navigated` event of the browser control and then check the browser's `Url` in your event handler.

There's more here on Microsoft Live's OAuth 2 implementation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn631818.aspx

And more here on responding to the `Navigated` event in the web browser control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx

I hope this helps.